# How to stop Amazon EC2 billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Every month I am being billed $0.80 + VAT for the following:

> Elastic Compute Cloud $0.80 US West (Oregon) Region   Usage
>
> EBS
>
> $0.10 per GB-month of General Purpose (SSD) provisioned storage - US West
> (Oregon)  8.000 GB-Mo $0.80
>
> Total: $0.80
>
> Region Total:  $0.80

I asked them to stop doing this and got the following response:

*I'm sorry that you have concerns relating to your recent billing. Here is the reason that you are being charged:
$0.10 per GB-month of General Purpose (SSD) provisioned storage - US West (Oregon)     Usage     8.00000136     0.8 USD*

*It appears that you stopped your instance but did not delete the storage that was attached.
I have as a one time courtesy refunded the charges to you from March as well as added a credit to your account to offset the current charges but would recommend deleting the storage to avoid accruing any further charges. It is located in the US West (Oregon) region.*

This is nice but I literally cannot find this attached storage anywhere. It does not appear in EC2.

Any ideas how I can stop getting billed a dollar a month?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Log in to your [AWS console](http://console.aws.amazon.com/)
2. Make sure that in the upper right corner you pick the 'US West (Oregon)' 
   region:

[image]

3. From the 'Services' menu in upper left corner, pick 'EC2'
4. On the left side menu, make sure that 'Instances', 'AMIs', 'Volumes' and 'Snapshots' are all empty

Comment: thanks so much.  No idea why but there was a stopped instance in Oregon.

Comment: It took me a good 30 minutes looking online for this specific answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you create EC2 t2 instances , it will use EBS as your instance root storage.

You may check this out under AWS console - EC2 - Volumes

Or under AWS Console - AMI  . check your instance AMI Root Device Type.